# Size of YouTube Subscribe Circle and Video Rectangle

Tags: youtube

I need to design custom **YouTube End Screen**.

What's the standard size of **Subscribe Circle** and **Video Rectangle**?

[image: Size of YouTube Subscribe Circle and Video Rectangle]

Comment: Just a comment: That is a lot to read! I didn't know what to look at first, and I didn't know what to click on. Take a look at some other YouTuber's end screens and copy their layout. Also, I have heard it is a lot easier to read if you divide the elements on the screen into 3 rows and 3 columns. You almost did that, but the column on the right has a different set of "rows" that don't match the middle column and the left column. (You could ask for help on the [StackExchange community for graphic design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).)

Comment: Is it possible to make this question appear on Graphic Design StackExchange without posting it there as a new thread?

Comment: I don't think so. Besides, you can ask your question in a way more related to graphic design! Like "This layout seems a little jumbled, but I can't figure out why. Any help?" (That's probably what I would write!)

Answer (score 1):

When using brand identifiers such as the YouTube Logo, you want to check what guidelines the brand has on using their brand resources. A quick [Google search](https://www.google.de/search?q=youtube%20logo%20guidelines) yields the official [Brand Resources guideline by YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/yt/about/brand-resources). Here you will find all you need:

> **Minimum size**
>
> The word "YouTube" should always be easy to read. So in digital
>   content the Logo should never appear smaller than 24dp in height.
>
> The minimum size for applying the Logo in print is 0.125 in/3.1 mm in
>   height.

Check the linked page for more details on the usage of the Logo.

**Sidenote:** Since YouTube belongs to Google, they use the terminology of Google's Material Design guidelines. *dp* stands for *Density-independent pixels*, you will find an explanation on that on the [Material Design website](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/units-measurements.html#units-measurements-pixel-density).

Comment: I'm sorry if this is off-topic. Where can I ask about this?

Comment: @Clicker I wouldv'e said graphicdesign.SE, but I just noticed the screenshot you added, which helps in the understanding of your question ... I guess that makes it fit for this site after all. Guess that means my answer is besides the point, but you won't get a better one. There isn't a defined standard for that, it's a question of good design (so this question might still be a fit for graphicdesign.SE, but again, you won't get precise pixel values as an answer, a good answer for that question will always be *it depends ...*)

Comment: I don't think this is off topic or too broad, but there's a decent chance it is primarily opinion based.  Either way, it's preferable not to answer if you feel a question is off topic.  I know it goes against the desire we all have to help people, but it ultimately leads to people asking questions they know are off-topic simply because they know they'll still get an answer before it closes.  The better bet is to comment to suggest where it should go (or even flag it for a moderator to move if it is a high enough quality question).  It is ok to answer when suggesting migration though.

Comment: @AJHenderson With the screenshot the question definitely makes more sense, it wasn't there when I posted my answer and the text wasn't much to go on, I misinterpreted the question a bit. It's still a low effort question though, so I doubt it would qualify for migration (since afaik only high-quality questions should be migrated in any case). I guess as it stands now the question is acceptable and my answer still applies to some extent, so I'll retract my vote.

Comment: @MoritzLost I was more commenting on the "don't answer if you don't think it fits" side of things.  It's something I know a lot of people do early on because they want to be helpful (believe me, I want to do it too), but the consensus is generally that it ends up being counter productive in the long run.